# Use router-link instead of web route in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, routes, vue-router

I am using laravel 9 and vue 3. When I visit a link through the clicking the menu, I am getting the result I expected. On the other hand, when I visit the same link through typing in the url or refreshing the page, I get a printed [object] result which is not what i wanted.

result when clicking the link (correct)
[image: result when clicking the link]

result when refreshing the page or typing the link in the url(incorrect)
[image: result when refreshing the page or typing the link in the url]

Below is some part of my code.

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
Route::get('{view}', ApplicationController::class)->where('view','(.*)');
```

**routes.js**

```
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.vue';
import ListUsers from './pages/users/ListUsers.vue';

export default[
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
    },

    {
        path: '/users',
        name: 'users',
        component: ListUsers,
    }
]
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function index() {
    $users = User::latest()->get();
    return $users;
}
```

**ListUsers.vue**

```
const getUsers = () => {
    axios.get('/users')
        .then((response) => {
            users.value = response.data;
        })
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the template code of `ListUsers.vue`?

Comment: @NehaSoni this is the link https://pastebin.com/4PN1Rihn. thank you

Answer (score -1):

The printed log should be the information of the currently logged in user.

You can search `console.log` globally in your vue project and find out which file is printed, delete it or comment it.